# JLabel suddenly gets large in size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I'm trying to create a window in java swing . 
First i create a **JFrame**, inside it i setup a :
**MenuBar,ToolBar,DrawingSurface(extends JPanel)**.
in **DrawingSurface** i override the method **paintComponent()** , so i can paint dynamically inside the Panel , the problem is that i tried adding two labels to the panel (calling two times to **public int registerInput(String name,String comp1,String comp2)** ) only one shows , i tried printing locations sizes ... for debuging, i found out that the drawing starts fine but after couple of iterations the second label suddenly gets too big and i suppose thats why it's not showing .
Here is the DrawingSurface class :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;




public class DrawingSurface extends JPanel{

    class DrawingObjects {
        public String name;
        public String comp1;
        public String comp2;
        float totalTcd;
        float totalTpd;
        int numberOfChanges;
        JLabel label;
        float surfaceY;
        float surfaceX;
    }
    private final int WidthFactor = 10;
    private final int HeightFactor = 5;
    private ArrayList<DrawingObjects> drawingObjects = new ArrayList<DrawingObjects>();

    DrawingSurface(){}
    public int registerInput(String name,String comp1,String comp2) {
        for(DrawingObjects dO :drawingObjects){
            if (dO.name.equals(name)){
                System.out.println("Object already exist in Drawing surface");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        DrawingObjects newObj = new DrawingObjects();
        newObj.name = name;
        newObj.comp1 = comp1;
        newObj.comp2 = comp2;
        //newObj.totalTcd = (float) tree.tcdComputing(tree.vertexes.get(comp1));
        //newObj.totalTpd = (float) tree.tpdComputing(tree.vertexes.get(comp1));
        newObj.numberOfChanges = 0;
        newObj.label = new JLabel(newObj.name,SwingConstants.CENTER);
        newObj.label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));

        int tmpWidth = (int) (getSize().getWidth()/WidthFactor);
        int tmpHeight = (int) (getSize().getHeight()/HeightFactor);
        newObj.label.setSize(tmpWidth,tmpHeight);
        System.out.println("Label "+(getSize().getWidth()/WidthFactor)+ " , "+(getSize().getHeight()/HeightFactor));
        System.out.println("Surface Height width "+getSize().getHeight()+" , "+getSize().getWidth());
        newObj.label.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(tmpWidth, tmpHeight));
        newObj.label.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(tmpWidth, tmpHeight));
        drawingObjects.add(newObj);
        add(newObj.label);
        return 0;
    }
    public void unregisterInput(String name) {
        for(DrawingObjects dO :drawingObjects){
            if (dO.name.equals(name))
                drawingObjects.remove(dO);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawObjLabels(g);
        drawObjWaves(g);
    }
    private void drawObjLabels(Graphics g){
        int index=0;
        for (DrawingObjects dO:drawingObjects){
            dO.label.setLocation(1, (int)(dO.label.getHeight() * index+1));
            System.out.println("Location x y : "+1+" , "+(dO.label.getHeight() * index+1));
            System.out.println("Label "+dO.label.getWidth()+" , "+dO.label.getHeight());
            System.out.println("Surface Height width "+getSize().getHeight()+" , "+getSize().getWidth());

            index++;
        }
    }
    private void drawObjWaves(Graphics g){

    }
}
```

and here is the code constructing it (a function inside another class):

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;



public class WaveDrawer {
    private JFrame mainWindow;
    private DrawingSurface drawingSurface;
    private boolean drawingState = false;
    private boolean editingState = false;


    private void setMenuBar(JFrame frame){
        JMenuItem screenshot = new JMenuItem("Export as Image");
        screenshot.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {}
        });

        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menu.add(screenshot);
        menu.add(exit);

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.add(menu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
    }
    private void setToolBar(JFrame frame){
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("States");


        JButton drawingButton = new JButton();
        drawingButton.setText("Drawing");
        toolBar.add(drawingButton);

        JButton editingButton = new JButton();
        editingButton.setText("Editing Circuit");

        toolBar.add(editingButton);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        mainWindow = new JFrame("WaveDrawer");
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setSize(1200, 400);

        setMenuBar(mainWindow);

        setToolBar(mainWindow);
        drawingSurface = new DrawingSurface();
        drawingSurface.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        drawingSurface.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLUE));
        Container contentPane = mainWindow.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(drawingSurface, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public WaveDrawer() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    /*
     * ========== API part
     */
    public int registerInput(String name,String comp1,String comp2) {
        return drawingSurface.registerInput(name,comp1, comp2);
    }

    public void unregisterInput(String name) {
        drawingSurface.unregisterInput(name);
    }
}
```

Here is a simple test with main :

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WaveDrawer wd = new WaveDrawer();
        wd.registerInput("aaa", "aaaa", "aaa");
        wd.registerInput("aaa2", "aaaa2", "aaa2");
        wd.registerInput("aaa3", "aaaa2", "aaa2");
        wd.registerInput("aaa4", "aaaa2", "aaa2");
    }

}
```

Here is the output of the console (my printing) :

```
Label 119.0 , 56.6
Surface Height width 283.0 , 1190.0
Label 119.0 , 56.6
Surface Height width 283.0 , 1190.0
Location x y : 1 , 1
Label 119 , 56
Surface Height width 283.0 , 1190.0
Location x y : 1 , 57
Label 119 , 56
Surface Height width 283.0 , 1190.0
Location x y : 1 , 1
Label 119 , 56
Surface Height width 313.0 , 1200.0
Location x y : 1 , 312
Label 1198 , 311
Surface Height width 313.0 , 1200.0
```

notice that suddenly the location and size of second label changes :

```
Location x y : 1 , 312
Label 1198 , 311
```

what is the problem here ?

Comment: One problem is that the question does not contain a minimal, **runnable** code example of the problem

Comment: You appear to be adding and removing GUI components from the paintComponent method via the `drawObjLabels(...)` method, something that should *never* be done. The `paintComponent` method should paint and paint only, and should not change a GUI's component structure or state. I wonder if your labels should be logical constructs and not GUI constructs -- hard to say with the given code, and I second @GilbertLeBlanc's request that you create and post a [mcve].

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels i've edited the code and remove the part of adding removing elements in paintcomponent .

Comment: What is your overall goal with this code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: im trying to simulate a circuit , each label represents a wire , next to it ill draw the Current (0 / 1) wave, the user can select which wire he wants to monitor thats why im adding it dynamically .

Comment: i mean i already have part of the code which implements the program to draw circuit and connect them , and using system timer can pass a current in the circuit , im trying to add the option to monitor wires and draw their current wave form .

Comment: Sounds interesting and complex -- much luck! I again wonder though if you should avoid using JLabels for this but instead work out your non-GUI model first, and then create a "view" or GUI classes which draws the visual representation of your circuit model in a single JPanel, and then allows for animation of the circuit.

Comment: I don't understand. When I launch I see 4 labels. If I resize, one of them disappears. I don't see any labels changing locations.